# NTh square free semi prime

Tags: math

I am trying to find the nth( n <= 2000000) [square free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) [semi prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime).  I have the following code to do so.

```
 int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    for(int j = i +1 ; j <= 2500; j++ )
    {
        semiprimes[k++] = (primes[i]*primes[j]);
    }
}
 sort(semiprimes,semiprimes+k);
```

`primes[]` is a list of primes.

My problem is, i get different values for `n = 2000000`, with different limits on the for loops. Could someone tell a way to correctly calculate these limits?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hint: the `n`th semiprime must be larger than `n`. If `p` is the largest prime less than `n/2`, then `2p` is a semiprime that should be included in your count.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Sax Could you please elaborate? I still have not figured it out! Keep taking the wrong limits.

Answer (score 2):

You want to calculate the nth **first** semi-prime square-free numbers. **"first"** means that you have to generate all of them under a certain value. Your method consist of generating a lot of those numbers, sort them and extract the nth first values.

This can be a good approach but you must have all the numbers generated. Having two different limits in your nested loops is a good way to miss some of them (in your example, you are not calculating `primes[1001]*primes[1002]` which should be in `semiprimes`).

To avoid this problem, you have to compute all the semi-prime numbers in a square, say `[1,L]*[1,L]`, where L is your limit for both loops.

To determine L, all you need is it to count.
Let N be the number of semi-prime square-free numbers under `primes[L-1]*primes[L-1]`.

`N = (L * L - L) / 2`

L*L is the total number of pairwise multiplications. L is the number of squares. This has two be divided by two to get the right number (because `primes[i]*primes[j] = primes[j]*primes[i]`).

You want to pick L such that n<=N. So for n = 2000000 :

```
    int L = 2001, k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1 ; j < L; j++ )
        {
            semiprimes[k++] = (primes[i]*primes[j]);
        }
    }
    sort(semiprimes,semiprimes+k);
```

Comment: This value of L is wrong!  See Jeffrey Sax's comment above.  You will be missing semiprimes that are of the type 2*p where p is a prime far beyond primes[2000].

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe an approach that works by computing all semiprimes inside a box will work in any reasonable amount of time.  Say we graph the factors (p,q) of the first 2 million semiprimes.  To make the graph more symmetric, let's plot a point for both (p,q) and (q,p).  The graph does not form a nice rectangular region, but instead looks more like the hyperbola y=1/x.  This hyperbola stretches out quite far, and iterating over the entire rectangle containing these will be a lot of wasted computation.

You may want to consider first solving the problem "how many semiprimes are there below N?" and then using a binary search.  Each query can be done in about sqrt(N) steps (hint: binary search strikes again).  You will need a fairly large table of primes, certainly at least up to 1 million, probably more.  Although this can be trimmed down by an arbitrarily large constant factor with some precomputation.